# Stabilizer of module in real quadratic number field

Tags: number-theory, integer-lattices

Let $K$ be a real quadratic number field and $M \subseteq K$ be a $\mathbb Z$-module of rank 2. Why is there a non-trivial $\varepsilon \in K$ with $M = \varepsilon M$. With non-trivial I mean $\varepsilon  \ne \pm 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The set $\mathcal{O}$ of $\alpha\in K$ with $\alpha M\subseteq M$
is an *order* in $K$, that is a subring of the form $\Bbb Z[\beta]$
with $\beta\notin\Bbb Z$. An order in a real quadratic field
has a unit $\varepsilon$ of infinite order (this is a power of the
fundamental unit, which lies in the ring of integers of $K$.)
Then $\varepsilon M=M$ and $\varepsilon\ne\pm1$.

Comment: How would you show that every order contains a power of the fundamental unit (and it's inverse)?

Comment: @Ravi If $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the ring of integers then $\mathcal{O}=\Bbb Z+N\mathcal{O_K}$. Some power of the fundamental unit is $\equiv1\pmod N$ and this lies in $\mathcal O$.

Comment: Aha I knew it would have to involve the conductor somehow but this is very precise. Thank you.

Comment: Can you recommend literature to the theory of orders? This is new to me, I guess I have to learn this.